# JAVA stand-alone .jar

Tags: java, jar

I am new to java and am trying to create a .jar that can be executed from any directory. I have spent a good amount of time search the web on how to do this, but it is just not sinking in. No matter what I have tried, I continue to get Error: Could not find or load main class. I am hoping someone can spell it out for me.. I have tried using the lib and classes folder (which never worked either), but would be happy just to stick all of the files in one directory if possible.

I have the following files at the root of d:\

- commons-lang3-3.5.jar
- JavaTemplate.class, JavaTemplate.java
- MANIFEST.txt
- Staples$1.class
- Staples.class
- Staples.java

## `javatemplate.JavaTemplate` is my main class:

```
package javatemplate;

import java.io.*;

// ====================
public class JavaTemplate {
// ====================

   // ====================
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   }
}
```

## my manifest.txt file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.7
Created-By: 1.8.0_111-b14 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: ./commons-lang3-3.5.jar 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: javatemplate.JavaTemplate
```

## from the command prompt at d:

```
"C:\Program Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\jar.exe cvfm JavaTemplate.jar ./Manifest.txt ./javatemplate.JavaTemplate ./*.java ./*.class
```

which compiles without errors

## Problem

Running `java -jar JavaTemplate.jar` results in the

> Error: Could not find or load main class

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you, RIck..

Comment: Download Netbeans. Create your program using Netbeans. Compile and run your program using Netbeans. Now your jar file is in your projects dist folder.

Comment: Off my head, shouldn't `MANIFEST.txt` be `MANIFEST.mf`

Comment: You might want to take a closer look at [Working with Manifest Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer The `jar -m` option takes care of that. It doesn't matter what the input manifest file is called.

Comment: @ejp Long time since I had to do this by hand

Comment: @MadProgrammer Me too ...

Answer (score 1):

```
jar.exe cvfm JavaTemplate.jar ./Manifest.txt ./javatemplate.JavaTemplate ./*.java ./*.class
```

This does not include `javatemplate/JavaTemplate.class`, so it isn't present in the .jar file.

NB:

1. Why are you putting .java files into the .jar file?
2. `./` is at best redundant in the `Class-path` entries. They are relative URLs, relative to the location of the .jar file.

Unclear what `./javatemplate.JavaTemplate` is supposed to be.

Comment: I am using Netbeans and have created the .jar, but once I move it to another location, it fails.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am using Netbeans and have created the .jar, but once I move it to another location, it fails. I mixed up a javac and jar commands, that is why the javatemplate.JavaTemplate was there.  Even running jar.exe cvfm JavaTemplate.jar ./Manifest.txt ./*.java ./*.class gives me the same error. I don't understand why it still cannot find the main class. What else am I missing?

Comment: You are missing exactly what I said in the first sentence of my answer. The `javatemplate/JavaTemplate.class` file. `./*.class*` isn't recursive.